# Facebook messenger link sharing does not work with a message

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, messenger

I can initiate dialog to send a link to Facebook Messenger. Everything goes fine and recepient gets the message with URL. However, when a message is added in Facebook's UI, only that message is received and URL NOT.

[Message field causes link to be ignored in received message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VLU4.png)

### Desktop

I have tried both methods according to
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog/

#### URL

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?display=page&link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com&app_id=<APP_ID>
```

#### SDK

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<APP_ID>',
          autoLogAppEvents: true,
          xfbml: true,
          version: 'v11.0',
        });
      };
```

```js
FB.ui({
  method: 'send',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog/',
});
```

I have tried different SDK versions and different APP IDs.

### Mobile

Curriosly so, **my setup for mobile works fine**, link is received with or without a message.

```
fb-messenger://share?=<APP_ID>&link=<MY_LINK>
```

I am really confused as there does not seem much to configure... Thanks in advance for any leads on this.

Answer (score 1):

It has been acknowledged as a bug by Facebook already in May https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/201777038410094/

Again reported in July
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2934678630125393/?join_id=f3c21b71e26d8c

Comment: They said it was fixed by June 2022 in the first link. Can anyone confirm that?